# How to use onchange on 2 input fields in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am trying to catch 2 input field's value but none of the input fields is working.

when I comment second Input field than the first one works properly.

```
  state = { zipcode: null, city: "" };

  onFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

   //Callback 
    this.props.onEnter(this.state.zipcode);
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input
            type="number"
            className={`form-control`}
            placeholder="Enter ZIP code"
            name="zipcode"
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input
            type="text"
            className={`form-control`}
            placeholder="Enter Zip-code"
            name="city"
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I hit enter after entering a query in the first input field I get no output and no error.

Comment: Why don't you have any `value` properties on your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it worked just fine. Maybe there is something wrong with your callback function. Because on form submission you are getting the correct values.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        zipcode: null, 
      city: ""
    }
  }

  onFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

   //Callback 
    console.log(this.state);
  };


  handleChange = event => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input
            type="number"
            className={`form-control`}
            placeholder="Enter ZIP code"
            name="zipcode"
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input
            type="text"
            className={`form-control`}
            placeholder="Enter Zip-code"
            name="city"
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is the `jsfiddle` link with your code. Check in the inspect element after clicking on the submit button. 
It works.

https://jsfiddle.net/t4o0xawr/1/

Comment: Thanks @vs_lala,
Is there any way I can use both the inputs without submit button? I mean with just enter can I submit the form?

Comment: @BasantPatidar If you will look at the basic construct of the HTML form, you will notice that on pressing the enter in a form triggers the click handler of the first `type="submit"` button. So, if you want to eliminate the button then you will have to manually capture the enter key and perform the desired action on it.